# need to store check boxes array in db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Iam trying to insert Array data (ie., checkbox values) into Mysql db (using Phpmyadmin)

when I try to store, iam getting as 'Array' for the field "forms" in db..

please someone tell me what changes I have to do for the below code, so I can store all the array values (seperated with commas in my db)

here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['forms']) && $_POST['forms']!=''){
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "eshop_orders";
        $forms=$wpdb->escape($_POST['forms']);


        $query1=$wpdb->query("UPDATE $table SET forms='$forms' where checkid='$checkid' limit 1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize) on the array before inserting the values, and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when you call the values from memory.

For example:

```
$data = serialize($_POST['forms']);
```

Comment: when I tried 'serialize', now its displaying in db as 's:5:"Array"'.. so, what I have to do now?

Comment: When you query the database, and get the `forms` row, you will need to call `unserialize` on it to get the original array

Comment: @Bob: no offense, but I'm not going to do your work for you.  Maybe you should look for a PHP book or tutorial or something.  If you'll work on your PHP skills, then eventually things like this will be easy for you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the array value to string using comma seperator and store it to db.

In Php there is an `implode` function to convert the array value to string using seperator.

```
 $value = implode(",", $forms);         
 echo $value;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php